# Is there any reason not to use optional parameters in a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

As part of my new job, I am working on adding new features for an existing project coded in C#. Part of my work involves updating stored procedures located on our SQL-Server. This process used to be quite a pain, since adding parameters to the stored procedure would often cause another part of the site to break, since changes to the parameter list of the stored procedure meant that calls to the stored procedure had to be updated site-wide.

The solution that I found to this was to use option parameters, such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doSomething  
 (  @Parameter1 NVARCHAR(50),
    @NewParameter INT = 1
 )
```

So that the new parameter would have a default value set, meaning that calls to it that don't include @NewParameter won't throw an exception. To me, this seems like an obvious solution, but I noticed that none of the stored procedures that are associated with this project have any optional parameters. I've also noticed in the past that when I find a new clever programming trick that no one else is using, there's usually a reason.

So, is there any technical reason not to use optional parameters in stored procedures? Does it hurt performance in some way? Are they compatibility issues or instances when an optional parameter might lead to undefined behaviour? Are there any dangers or warnings that I should be aware of?

Comment: Having a parameter with default value is just a fix which would/could bite you back in future. May be that is why they are not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not run into any issues when using optional parameters in stored procedures in .net.  However in a past code base I worked on in an older version of ColdFusion - there was a field called dbprocparam name or similar, it did not matter what you put in as the name, the parameters would be passed in sequentially.

e.g.

```
exec proc_1
 @1 bit ,
 @2 bit ,
 @3 bit
```

if i called the SP as (but imagine CF syntax)
    exec proc_1
     @2 = 1
     @3 = 1
     @1 = 0

the proc would actually hit profiler as "exec proc_1 1, 1, 0" when it should have been "exec proc_1 0, 1, 1"

This became a problem when adding optional parameter's to stored procedures *NOT* at the bottom of the parameter list.  This is one of the potential issues with modifying param list on multiple use SPs.

Just something to watch out for, I've only experienced this with old coldfusion, but it could exist elsewhere as well.

Comment: Well, I take it that based on the inactivity of this question, there's not too much to worry about. Thank you for your answer though, I will make sure to keep an eye out for that!